# python: when making a list of lists do i have to contain them in square brackets?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

so whats the difference between:

```
x = [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]
```

and

```
x = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]
```

do the square brackets around the second option do anything?

Comment: First one will create a tuple of lists, second one will create a list of lists.

Comment: @AvinashRaj both examples work

Comment: Did you  try printing both to see what you had?

Answer (score 7):

```
x = [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]
```

Will create a tuple with lists

```
x = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]
```

Will create lists of list

i.e.)

```
x = [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]
x
([1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1])
type(x)
<type 'tuple'>

"a","b"
('a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one creates a tuple of lists , while the second one creates a list of lists.

tuples are immutable, whereas lists are mutable.

Example for 1st one -

```
>>> x = [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]
>>> x
([1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1])
>>> x[0] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Example for 2nd one -

```
>>> x = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]
>>> x
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> x[0] = 1
>>> x
[1, [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Without the brackets it is a tuple:

```
>>> x = [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]
>>> x
([1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1])
>>> type(x)
<type 'tuple'>
```

You can't modify the items in a tuple.

With `[]` is it a list:

```
>>> x = [[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1]]
>>> x
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> type(x)
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one is the same as doing this :

`x = ([1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1])`

This is a tuple of lists.